# How to add attribute data-val-required if it is removed dynamically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, unobtrusive-validation, unobtrusive-javascript

I want to remove attribute on some condition so i used this

```
$("#tab-1").removeAttr("data-val-required");
```

But now on some conditions i want to make it required again
i have used this but it doesnt work

```
$("#tab-1").rules("add", "required")
```